# python poetry (env use) not recognizing python version (windows)

Tags: python, windows, powershell, path, python-poetry

I have to work on windows for a python project. Got two versions of python installed (3.7 and 3.10), poetry is set up properly, but I cannot get poetry to work with python3.10:

```
PS > poetry env use C:\Users\Foo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe

The specified Python version (3.7.2) is not supported by the project (^3.10).
Please choose a compatible version or loosen the python constraint specified in the pyproject.toml file.

PS > C:\Users\Foo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe --version
Python 3.10.2

PS > python --version
Python 3.7.2
```

It's as if the path I specify in `env use` is ignored. My expectation is that a direct specification of the path using `poetry env use ...` should pick up python 3.10 in this case. Clearly I'm specifying the correction version, yet somehow it reverts to 3.7.

Also python is on the path:

```
PS > $env:Path -split ';'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\Scripts\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\
...
C:\Users\Foo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\
C:\Users\Foo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\
C:\Users\Foo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher\
C:\Users\Foo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Scripts\
C:\Users\Foo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts
```

Not sure if the global system path to `Python37-32` is an issue here. Anyway I don't have admin rights and must solve this in userland.

Looking for the python command directly finds the global (system) python:

```
PS > Get-Command python

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     python.exe                                         3.7.215... C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-...
```

Trying the above in `cmd` instead of powershell yields the same results. Nothing changes on restart of PS, cmd, vsc (visual studio code) and the entire os (for good measure).

How do I get poetry to pick up the python3.10 binary?

Oh, I'm on the latest version of poetry (1.4.1) and installed with the official installer. I previously had an older version installed, that worked.

---

**Workaround / halfway solution**

Curiously enough, vsc allows me to select python 3.10 `Select Interpreter` - it offers me the a previously created poetry environment (from `C:\Users\Foo\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs`) as well as directly the python3.10 binary under the same path that I unsucessfully tried above. When I select one of these, I get a "python cmd"-terminal in vsc within which poetry works fine.

So far so good, but now I want to set the environment to the project directory `poetry config virtualenvs.in-project true`. The command returns without error (and a check confirms that the setting is active), but there is no local environment created. Calling `poetry install` from the vsc "python cmd"-terminal results in no changes (because *this* environment is fine) and calling `poetry install` from the powershell doesn't work because it cannot find the proper python version. (Also presumably I cannot create a new environment for a different project.)

A dirty workaround that worked: I copied the existing poetry env into the project directory, renamed it `.venv` and set it as active environment in vsc via 'Select Interpreter'. This solves my immediate issue.

I'm leaving this here as a question because I still don't get why `poetry env use` is not working and to leave the workaround here in case it helps someone running into similar issues.

**EDIT:**
(not a solution, but this works for me for what it's worth)

Since this question seems to get many visits, here's a little follow-up. Working more with poetry, I nowadays tend to delete all virtual envs and poetry itself, keeping only the config files for the particular project. Then quickly run the current poetry installer and install a new env with the latest poetry version. That's almost always faster than figuring out where something went wrong on windows.

If you are working with different python versions, I found it best on windows to use the official windows installer for that version and restrict the installation to the single user running the installer (the installer asks). That doesn't require admin rights or influence the wider system and works well these days with poetry. I'm running a number of different projects and python versions like this on the same machine.

If you can, avoid developing on windows, compared to linux it's a hot mess.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `poetry`, but it looks like you have a bootstrapping problem: your `poetry env use` call itself fails, so you never get to configure the desired Python interpreter. As the error message suggests, perhaps the solution is to temporarily allow v3.7 to be used via the `pyproject.toml` file - just so you can successfully make your `poetry env use` call.